# When can I set the visibility of a table cell?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to set the visibility of a table cell:

```
<td id="tdSection1" runat="server">
...

</td>
```

For some reason once I hide the cell based on a dropdown selection, I cannot make it visible again.

I am doing this in the Page_Load event, is this correct?

When I debug, I have a method that returns true/false and I can see it with my own eyes that it is setting the .Visible to TRUE yet it remains FALSE.

It must be a timing issue?

```
bool displayRow = DisplaySectionRow(userId);
tdSection1.Visible = displayRow;
```

When in debug mode, displayRow is true yet the Visible property still returns false.

Not sure what is going on....

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I updated with the code, not sure if it will help.

Comment: @coolbreeze Where in your code you make this `<td>` invisible?

Comment: What does DisplaySectionRow method do?

Comment: @abramlimpin it returns either true or false based on the userId

Comment: You have to post the code from 'DisplaySectionRow' since the issue is that you can't display the table cell.